# Inserting PHP into PHP existent statements

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and Custom Fields - however, I'm trying to pull a custom field with PHP to fill in the "form" code inside a PHP statement

I'm not not too familiar with PHP, but here is what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php $form1 = '<?php echo get_field('form_code'); ?>'; echo do_shortcode( $form1 ) ?>
```

I basically want to fill the form value with the value in the custom field in wordpress.

Any help would be appreciated guys <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do it how you typed, nor would/should it work.  Just set the variable with the get field function.

```
<?php 
$form1 = get_field('form_code'); 
echo do_shortcode( $form1 ); 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's done it - you're a star, I'm currently learning PHP (2nd day) so your help is appreciated!

Comment: go through codeacademy and w3schools courses.  Free and definitely helpful for beginners.

Comment: Ack.  PLEASE don't put two commands on the same line - separate them with line feeds.  And put that semicolon on the end of the second command.

Comment: Yea I was being lazy and not reformatting the source code from OP.  Fixed.